Android.Provider.Settings+SettingNotFoundException
I designed a .net MAUI App but my app shut down immediately i run , so i ran it in debug mode and it throws this exception immediately on the line InitializeComponent(); of my homepage.xaml.cs
`
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> Android.Provider.Settings+SettingNotFoundException: animator_duration_scale
I have tried checking the andriodmanifest.xml but all my efforts proofed fatal.
i have also checked on the animation_duration_scale for .net 8 which shows it has been obsolete.
i am  still finding my feet around .net MAUI.
Possible Solutions will be appreciated.

If possible, create a minimal repro on GitHub

i have, it is accessible via www.github.com/jalalgorithm/expensetrackerapp

The first attempt I removed the following code and it works fine:
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,-20,0,0">
    <syncfusion:SfAccordion AutoScrollPosition="Top" AnimationEasing="SinOut">
        <syncfusion:SfAccordion.Items>
            ...
            ...
        </syncfusion:SfAccordion.Items>
    </syncfusion:SfAccordion>
</Grid>


Then I have updated all packages and it works:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="communitytoolkit.maui" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="communitytoolkit.mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="refractored.mvvmhelpers" Version="1.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlitepclraw.core" Version="2.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlitepclraw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3" Version="2.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.buttons" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.calendar" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.charts" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.core" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.datagrid" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.expander" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.picker" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.popup" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.progressbar" Version="25.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="syncfusion.maui.tabview" Version="25.2.7" />
</ItemGroup>


** Note that the app is still shutting down due to license I think, but the main issue solved. **
